# Facing an error while executing the plotly module

Tags: pandas, plotly, plotly-python, yfinance

I am running the below-mentioned code to create a candlestick chart with traces but an error is being reflected as
Exception has occurred: AttributeError
'dict' object has no attribute 'add_trace'

The code is as follows

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import yfinance as yf
import plotly.offline
from plotly.offline import init_notebook_mode, iplot, iplot_mpl

a=input("Enter symbol of the company\n")
tick1=a+'.NS'
HD=yf.Ticker(tick1)
His=HD.history(period='3mo',interval='1d')
His.reset_index(inplace=True)
His['20wma']=His['Close'].rolling(window=140).mean()
fig={"data":[go.Candlestick(x=His['Date'],open=His['Open'],high=His['High'],low=His['Low'],close=His['Close'])]}
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=His['Date'],y=His['20wma'],line=dict(color="e0e0e0")))
plotly.offline.plot(fig)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For graph_objects, go.Figure() is the correct way to write it. Figure() is the correct way to write it. And the color setting needs the hexadecimal notation #.

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import yfinance as yf
import plotly.offline
from plotly.offline import init_notebook_mode, iplot, iplot_mpl

a=input("Enter symbol of the company\n")
tick1=a # edit
# rick1=a+'.NS'
HD=yf.Ticker(tick1)
His=HD.history(period='3mo',interval='1d')
His.reset_index(inplace=True)
His['20wma']=His['Close'].rolling(window=20).mean()
fig=go.Figure(data=(go.Candlestick(
    x=His['Date'],
    open=His['Open'],
    high=His['High'],
    low=His['Low'],
    close=His['Close'])))

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
    x=His['Date'],
    y=His['20wma'],
    mode='lines',
    line=dict(color="#e0e0e0")))
plotly.offline.plot(fig)
```

[image]

Comment: I've modified some of the parts defining stocks, and I've posted the graphs I got from APPL. Also, the moving average has been corrected to 20 days.

Answer (score 0):

You can create figures from dictionaries or from graph objects.

In your example, you create `fig` as a standard python dictionary. It only becomes a graph object once you plot it. `add_trace` is not a valid python command for a dictionary, that's why it fails.

You want to create a graph object, to which you can apply `add_trace`. See [here](https://plotly.com/python/creating-and-updating-figures/)